Why is gnome shell eating over 30% of my processor on 24.04.1? what might resolve it?

Running an AMD Ryzen 5 2600X (6 core x 12).
I've run Ubuntu 22.04 for quite some time (over 2 years).
Just upgraded to 24.04.1 last night and I hear my fans going wild constantly now.
I check the processor and see that gnome-shell is eating process like candy.
This is constant.  Never seen this before.
What is the resolution?
System Details Report
Report details

Date generated:                              2024-10-21 08:40:03

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M DS3H WIFI
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600X × 12
Graphics:                                    Software Rendering
Disk Capacity:                               500.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F41
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-47-generic


I rebooted and chose Ubuntu Classic (X11) and started all the same apps and now you can see that gnome-shell is at (max) 9.2%.

Most of the time now it is less than 9.2%
Idles around 5% or so.

It's not reproducible on my hardware. If you can reproduce this reliably, then please file a bug report.

List enabled extensions (if you have some enabled) using gnome-extensions list and disable them one by one using gnome-extensions disable <extension> (or do that from the GUI), while monitoring CPU usage. If at some point the CPU usage drops down and becomes acceptable, you have your culprit.

For me disabling ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com cure constantly eating 30% of CPU usage even if nothing happens.
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
